# Conditional summation in spreadtab

Tags: conditionals, spreadtab

I have a table with a column contains some numbers, positive and negative ones.

I want to make a summation of positive and negative numbers separately, but I don't want to mention the cell addresses in `sum` macros explicitly.

I don't know is there any way to do this automatically? My table is similar to the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{spreadtab}

\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{r|c}}
         1 & randint(-10, 10)  \\
         \STcopy{v}{a1+1} & randint(-10, 10)  \\ 
          & randint(-10, 10)  \\ 
          & randint(-10, 10)  \\ 
          & randint(-10, 10)  \\ 
          & randint(-10, 10)  \\ 
          & randint(-10, 10)  \\ 
          & randint(-10, 10)  \\ 
\hline
    @Total Sum &  :={sum(b1:[0,-1])}\\  
    @Pos. Nums Sum &  \\
    @Neg. Nums Sum  & \\  
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use helping columns which you hide:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{rc}}
  1 & \STcopy{v}{randint(-10, 10)}
    & \STcopy{v}{ifgt(!b1,0,!b1,0)}\SThidecol
    & \STcopy{v}{iflt(!b1,0,!b1,0)}\SThidecol \\
  \STcopy{v}{a1+1} &&& \\ 
   &&&\\ 
   &&&\\ 
   &&&\\ 
   &&&\\ 
   &&&\\ 
   &&&\\ 
  \midrule
  @Total Sum     & :={sum(b1:[0,-1])} &&\\  
  @Pos. Nums Sum & :={sum(c1:[1,-2])} &&\\
  @Neg. Nums Sum & :={sum(d1:[2,-3])} &&\\  
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```